# How do I join separate json objects output from a for loop into an array?

Tags: javascript, json, loops, casperjs

I am scraping websites using CasperJS and one of the tasks involve crawling across url set by a for loop counter. The url looks like this

`www.example.com/page/no=`

where the no is any number from 0-10 set by the for loop counter. The scraper then goes through all the pages, scrapes the data into a JSON object and repeats until no=10.

The data that I am trying to get is stored in discrete groups in each page- what I would like to work with is a single JSON object by joining all the scraped output from each page.

Imagine Page1 has Expense 1 and the object I am getting is { expense1 } and Page 2 has Expense 2 and object that I am getting is { expense2 }. What I would like to have is one JSON at the end of scraping that looks like this:

```
    scrapedData = {
       "expense1": expense1,
       "expense2": expense2,
     }
```

What I am having trouble is joining all the JSON object into one array.

I initialized an empty array and then each object gets pushed to array.
I have tried a check where if iterator i in for loop is equal to 10, then the JSON object is printed out but that didnt seem to work. I looked up and it seems Object spread is an option but I am not sure how to use it this case.

Any pointers would be helpful. Should I be using any of the array functions like map?

```
casper.then(function(){    

   var url = "https:example.net/secure/SaFinShow?url=";    
    //We create a for loop to go open the urls

    for (i=0; i<11; i++){

      this.thenOpen(url+ i, function(response){

          expense_amount = this.fetchText("td[headers='amount']");

          Date = this.fetchText("td[headers='Date']");

          Location = this.fetchText("td[headers='zipcode']");

          id = this.fetchText("td[headers='id']");


          singleExpense = {

              "Expense_Amount": expense_amount,
              "Date": Date,
              "Location": Location,
              "id": id
            };

          if (i ===10){
            expenseArray.push(JSON.stringify(singleExpense, null, 2))
            this.echo(expenseArray);
          }
      });

    };
});
```

Comment: any reason you are stringifying objects before pushing?

Comment: I got an error otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example and expanding on it, you should be able to do something like:

```
// Initialize empty object to hold all of the expenses
var scrapedData = {};

casper.then(function(){    

   var url = "https:example.net/secure/SaFinShow?url=";    
    //We create a for loop to go open the urls

    for (i=0; i<11; i++){

      this.thenOpen(url+ i, function(response){

          expense_amount = this.fetchText("td[headers='amount']");

          Date = this.fetchText("td[headers='Date']");

          Location = this.fetchText("td[headers='zipcode']");

          id = this.fetchText("td[headers='id']");


          singleExpense = {

              "Expense_Amount": expense_amount,
              "Date": Date,
              "Location": Location,
              "id": id
            };
          // As we loop over each of the expenses add them to the object containing all of them
          scrapedData['expense'+i] = singleExpense;
      });

    };
});
```

After this runs the `scrapedData` variable should be of the form:

```
scrapedData = {
  "expense1": expense1,
  "expense2": expense2
}
```

### Updated code

One problem with the above code is that inside the for loop when you loop over the expenses, the variables should be local. The variable names also should not be `Date` and `Location` since those are built-in names in JavaScript.

```
// Initialize empty object to hold all of the expenses
var scrapedData = {};

casper.then(function(){    

   var url = "https:example.net/secure/SaFinShow?url=";    
    //We create a for loop to go open the urls

    for (i=0; i<11; i++){

      this.thenOpen(url+ i, function(response){
          // Create our local variables to store data for this particular
          // expense data
          var expense_amount = this.fetchText("td[headers='amount']");

          // Don't use `Date` it is a JS built-in name
          var date = this.fetchText("td[headers='Date']");
          // Don't use `Location` it is a JS built-in name
          var location = this.fetchText("td[headers='zipcode']");

          var id = this.fetchText("td[headers='id']");


          singleExpense = {

              "Expense_Amount": expense_amount,
              "Date": date,
              "Location": location,
              "id": id
            };

          // As we loop over each of the expenses add them to the object containing all of them
          scrapedData['expense'+i] = singleExpense;
      });

    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks foe helping out! One thing I would like to point out is the scrapedData object is within the scope of this.thenOpen() function, if I were to call it, it should be within that function. Should I be printing/returning the scrapedData?

Comment: If I do this.echo(JSON.stringify(scrapedData, null, 2)) after scrapedData['expense'+i] = singleExpense; the result I get is this format:

{
  "expense9": {    
  }
}
{
  "expense9": {    
  }
}

not exactly JSON :/

Comment: @pk666777 Yeah you could return `scrapedData` from your function. 
So part of the problem was that inside the loop where you grab the data from the page, you were using variables defined elsewhere that had names that would class with the JS built-in objects names. I changed `Date` -> `date` and `Location` to `location`. Also, when doing `JSON.stringify` if the object has any data that cannot be converted to valid JSON, such as `undefined` then it will drop both the key and the value. `console.log` your scraped data to check it. Also your `fetchText` method probably should rely on the response